# Send database Data to Printer

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, printing

I would like to print some data from a MySql database on my default printer.
What is the best way to do that?

My data looks like this:

```
+---------------------+
|Number |Name |Address|
+---------------------+
| 1     |Tom  |1st Av.|
+---------------------+
```

I need grid lines printed and later I want to cut out that tables and glue it somewhere. So I am thinking about putting as much tables as possible on a piece of paper.

I have no idea how to do that. Any ideas?

Edit: This is for private use - so I can't use expensive software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option could be generate a simple `html` document with table and print it.

Comment: You guys were supposed to provide details, as I am looking for the code, how you exported Datatable to HTML

Answer (score 2):

The most easy way is to use PrintDocument + DataGrid

```
private void printGrid_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   printDocument1.Print();
}
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(System.Object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   PaintEventArgs myPaintArgs = new PaintEventArgs(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), this.Size));
   this.InvokePaint(dataGrid1, myPaintArgs);
}
```

Please note: the following conditions may cause an exception:

1. You do not have permission to access the printer.
2. There is no printer installed.

Answer (score 0):

You have number of options here. You may choose crystal report or Microsoft report or just use printing API (Draw on bitmap and print it).

Comment: What would be the fastest way to do it? (I can't use Crystal Report)